# Get Colour Formatted table in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have an two pandas dataframe like this:

**Df1**:

```
Name Age Hobby
ABC  23  Reading
GHI  25  Playing
```

**DF2**:

```
Name    Age      Hobby
Green  Yellow    Green 
Green  NaN       Red
```

What I am looking is 3rd data-frame which makes a df in such a way that:

1. ABC and GHI are colured in Green
2. 23 is in Yellow and 25 remains white as it is Nan
3. Reading in Green and Playing in Red

Any help on the same

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [styles](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/style.html) with custom function:

```
def color(x): 
   c = 'background-color: '
   return Df2.apply(lambda x: x.str.lower()).radd(c).fillna('')


Df1.style.apply(color,axis=None).to_excel('styled.xlsx', engine='openpyxl', index=False)
```

---

**Output**
[image]

Comment: is this new df will be in `excel` or a pandas dataframe ?

Comment: @RahulAgarwal - Here is output styler object from `df.style.apply(color,axis=None)` and for excel need `to_excel`.

Comment: I want to save it in a new df or the the df1 being modified

Comment: `display(df1.style.apply(color,axis=None))` will return it in the console @RahulAgarwal. Good one jez, upvoted

Comment: @anky_91: I am getting this `<pandas.io.formats.style.Styler at 0x18da7b49ba8>` while running the code

Comment: For both I am getting almost the same output..print or display

Comment: @RahulAgarwal i edited the post with my results using this code. :)

Comment: Tell me one more thing..if I do `df3 = Df1.style.apply(color,axis=None)`. will it save in new variable..till I figure this out why the same thing is not working for me!!

Comment: @RahulAgarwal - because you save styler object.

Comment: @jezrael: How to save this in new df

Comment: @RahulAgarwal - in my opinion it is not possible, because it is `Df2` for you. Is not possible save styler object like dataframe, you can only print it or write to excel.

Comment: Instead of excel can I save the same the same to ppt ?

Comment: @RahulAgarwal - hmmm, I think not, because pandas cannot write to ppt, not exist function. So only way write to excel and excel to ppt. Or create html is another way,  with `print(Df1.style.apply(color,axis=None).render())`

Comment: Ok thanks!! I will try if not...ask a new question!! Thanks for all the help!!

Comment: @RahulAgarwal - Btw, styler object working best in anaconda notebooks, so if possible, use it there.